# Regular expression for returning list of emails after specific set of chars (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have string like this :

```
To: sandy.lewis@test.com,alewis@testpage.com, drtmirk@test.org.au
```

I need to search for "**To:** ", and parse whatever after that for emails .

I know the email regx is `\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*` ,
so when I want to add **To** in the regx it will be

```
var senderRgx = new Regex(@"(?<=To: )\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*")
```

but this one will return *only the **first** email after **To*** . I need list of all emails
any help?

Comment: Without using regex approach:
1) replace everything include the `:` with empty string
2) now turn split the string on the commas `'`

Comment: One of those examples, where Regex just adds another problem. While you could make this _a lot_ more readable without regex, **your regex does not cover the full spec of valid emails**. So, Jazb's suggestion actually makes a lot more sense. Cut out the "To: " and split by whatever your separator is. I'd add a trim to that. Then you can decide if you want to validate the resulting addresses for a subset of the spec or how else to go on from there.

Comment: One does not have to cover the "Full Spec of valid emails". This is not an email validator, the OP is parsing an existing setup of *validated* emails already. All one has to do is consume text to either a space or a comma which signifies the end of the email. I provide such an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
(?:To:\s+|\G(?!^))(?:,\s*)?([^\s@,]+@[^\s@,]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group
- `To:\s+` Match `To:` and 1+ whitespace chars

  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match to get consecutive matches
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?:,\s*)?` Optionally match a comma and optional whitespace chars
- `([^\s@,]+@[^\s@,]+)` Capture group 1, match non whitespace chars with a single @ char

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3aTo%3a%5cs%2b%7c%5cG%28%3f!%5e%29%29%28%3f%3a%2c%5cs*%29%3f%28%5b%5e%5cs%40%2c%5d%2b%40%5b%5e%5cs%40%2c%5d%2b%29&i=To%3a+sandy.lewis%40test.com%2calewis%40testpage.com%2c+drtmirk%40test.org.au+%2c) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/UFzRvj).

[image]

For example

```
string pattern = @"(?:To:\s+|\G(?!^))(?:,\s*)?([^\s@,]+@[^\s@,]+)";
string input = @"To: sandy.lewis@test.com,alewis@testpage.com, drtmirk@test.org.au ,";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: This is misleading,  "Match To: and ...whitespace chars"? It is being captured, but not matched; as per the `(?: ... )` construct you specify. Also why is there the option of `MultiLine`? Nowhere in your pattern is a `.` or a `$` which `MultiLine` speaks to directly. Multiline changes the scope of the `.` and `$` to represent every line, not just the beginning of the buffer and the end of the buffer.

Comment: I misspoke, multiline is `^` and `$` and not the `.` . I see the `(?!^)` which I am guessing invalidates the match if hit. Seems like a touch overkill. IMHO

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Thank you for your comment. The `Match To: and 1+ whitespace chars ` are matched but not captured. Indeed  you don't need the multiline, I think it was from auto generated code. This part `(?!^)` prevent continuous matches without the `To: ` as the position will be at the start of the string where `\G` also matches.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't to use regular expressions, you can try the code below:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var senders = "To: sandy.lewis@test.com, alewis@testpage.com, drtmirk@test.org.au,";
            string [] emails = senders.Split();
            emails = emails.Where(i => i != "To:").ToArray();
            foreach(var email in emails)
               Console.WriteLine("{0}", email.Replace(",",""));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: You can split by ",", then trim the results. I wouldn't rely on " " being present.

Answer (score 0):

In regex one can create a pattern which consumes characters that are **not** of a specific type. That pattern is `[^ ]+` where the `^` in this context means *not*.

Because emails can't have spaces or commas, we will consume the email up to a space or comma. We will use the named match group `(?<{Name Here})` so we don't have to index `[0]` into the match group.

Since that pattern will repeat itself for each email, we will subsequently *capture* them together `( ... )+` in a single match and then extract those *match captures* as such which will hold each individual email.

```
var pattern = @"To:\s*((?<Email>[^,\s]+)[\s,]*)+";

var data = @"To: sandy.lewis@test.com,alewis@testpage.com, drtmirk@test.org.au";

var emails = Regex.Match(data, pattern)
                  .Groups["Email"]
                  .Captures.Cast<Capture>()
                           .Select(cpt => cpt.Value)
                           .ToList();


Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, emails));
```

###### Output

```
sandy.lewis@test.com 
alewis@testpage.com 
drtmirk@test.org.au
```